# My exception-safe Stack is running without finishing

Tags: c++, clion

I'm implementing an exception-safe Stack data structure with its common functionality in Clion, but unfortunately, when I run the example it starts but doesn't give any result...something like hanging and non-responding. Any ideas to resolve the issue?

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <initializer_list>

namespace my
{
    template<typename T>
    void destroy(T* p_ptr) {
        p_ptr->~T();
    }

    template<typename FwdIt>
    void destroy(FwdIt begin, FwdIt end) {
        while(begin != end) {
            destroy(begin);
        }
        ++begin;
    }

    template<typename T>
    class StackImpl {
    public:
        using value_type         = T;
        using reference          = T&;
        using const_reference    = const T&;
        using rval_reference     = T&&;
        using pointer_type       = T*;
        using const_pointer_type = const T*;
        using size_type          = std::size_t;
    public:
        StackImpl(size_type capacity = 0) : m_ptr {static_cast<pointer_type>
                                                         ( !capacity ?
                                                           nullptr :
                                                           operator new(sizeof(size_type) * capacity))},
                                            m_capacity{capacity},
                                            m_size{0}
            {}
        ~StackImpl() {
            my::destroy(m_ptr, m_ptr + m_capacity);
            operator delete(m_ptr);
        }
    public:
        pointer_type m_ptr;
        size_type m_capacity;
        size_type m_size;

    private:
        StackImpl(const StackImpl<value_type>&) = delete;
        StackImpl& operator=(const StackImpl<value_type>&) = delete;
    };
} 

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  my::StackImpl<int> myStack(10);
}
```

Comment: Have you investigated the running test using your debugger?  That should tell you exactly where the test is hanging.

Comment: `operator new(sizeof(size_type) * capacity)` doesn't look right. Shouldn't that be `sizeof(value_type) * capacity`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with googletest, the constructor `StackImpl::StackImpl(size_type )` hangs.

Comment: Thank you all for fixes)

Comment: You should also call `destroy` only on objects which have actually been constructed, so only on the range `[m_ptr, m_ptr + m_size]`. For `int` it happens to not make a difference, but for non-trivial types it will have undefined behavior otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

It hangs in the destructor. The loop is wrong, The condition `begin != end` is `true` for ever.

```
template<typename FwdIt>
void destroy(FwdIt begin, FwdIt end) {
    while(begin != end) {
        destroy(begin);
    }
    ++begin;
}
```

must be

```
template<typename FwdIt>
void destroy(FwdIt begin, FwdIt end) {
    while(begin != end) {
        destroy(begin);
        ++begin;
    }
}
```